# Delete set of directories using find command without running into argument list too long

Tags: linux, shell, unix, find

I am in a situation where I have the /tmp directory having atleast 25,000 - 50,000 directories in it. I am trying to use the following command to delete the directories which are older than 2 days in that directory.

```
find /path/to/tmp/* -type d -ctime +2 -delete
```

But I keep running into the error that the argument list is too long. How can I specifically limit the number of directories being deleted? I tried using the maxdepth 1 option as well and that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `*` glob causes the shell to expand all of the directory names out and pass them to `find`. Get rid of it and let `find` do the work rather than the shell.

```
find /path/to/tmp/ -mindepth 1 -type d -ctime +2 -delete
```

`-mindepth 1` ensures that `find` will only process subdirectories and not `/path/to/tmp` itself.

If these directories aren't empty you'll need to switch `-delete` to `rm -r`.

```
find /path/to/tmp/ -mindepth 1 -type d -ctime +2 -exec rm -r {} +
```

Comment: I tried the command and it complains that directories are not empty. I thought the -delete covered that. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JohnKugelman : Just for completeness - your solution is not exactly equivalent. In the original script, a directory `/path/to/tmp/.x` would not be deleted, while in your case it would be deleted. Maybe this is no problem for the OP, but we can't be sure.

Comment: @chrisrhyno2003 : `rm -r` should take care of this situation. Do you get any additional error message, which says that one of the files could not be deleted? Please show a transcript of your command and the resulting output.